# What is the cheapest public transportation from the Madrid airport to downtown?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, madrid, mad

I am going to Madrid for one night so I want to see downtown Madrid.  Because I am just a student with limited budget I am wondering what is the cheapest way to go from the airport of Madrid Terminal 1 to downtown Madrid?

Comment: Walking or hitchiking would be the cheapest! Or are you after something public transport related?

Comment: as I will be madrid for very limited time ( from 20.30 to 00.00 ) I prefer something public transport related to save me some time

Comment: Did you try reading the [WikiVoyage page for the airport](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Madrid%E2%80%93Barajas_Airport)?

Comment: no, didn't even know it existed lol, thank you for the link

Comment: Walking, it's free

Comment: @zeocrash : try reading my first comment ^^

Comment: Joke's still funny :P

Answer (score 3):

Bus is the best mode of transport for your limited budget. It's available 24/7 and runs every 15 minutes during the day and every 35 minutes at night.The tickets cost five euros and you can purchase it on the bus.

Comment: Thank you, You wouldn't know how much time it takes ? from the airport to downtown using the bus

Comment: It takes approximately 40 minutes. :)